# Writing a multipage tif to file in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, tiff

I'm trying to write a a multipage (1024 pages to be exact) to file.

```
for frame=1:num_images
    imwrite(output(:,:,frame), 'output.tif', 'tif', 'WriteMode', 'append', 'compression', 'none');
end
```

I tried this, but writing Int32 to tiff is not supported by imwrite.
I've also tried

```
tiffObj = Tiff('output.tif', 'w');
tiffObj.setTag('ImageLength', x_size);
tiffObj.setTag('ImageWidth', y_size);
tiffObj.setTag('Photometric', Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack);
tiffObj.setTag('BitsPerSample', 32);
tiffObj.setTag('SamplesPerPixel', 1);
tiffObj.setTag('RowsPerStrip', 64);
tiffObj.setTag('SampleFormat', Tiff.SampleFormat.Int);
tiffObj.setTag('TileWidth', 128);
tiffObj.setTag('TileLength', 128);
tiffObj.setTag('Compression', Tiff.Compression.None);
tiffObj.setTag('PlanarConfiguration',Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);
tiffObj.setTag('Software', 'MATLAB');
tiffObj.write(output);
tiffObj.close();
```

The tif I imread() has 1 SamplesPerPixel per frame, but when I try to use the same value I get

> SamplesPerPixel is 1, but the number of image planes provided was 1204.

If I set it to 1204 Imagej complains

> Unsupported SamplesPerPixel: 1204

This is rather frustrating.

Comment: What about : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35684-save-and-load-data-as-multi-frame-tiff-format

Comment: To be quite honest I didn't realize that there was a download button so at first I didn't understand where the function he talked about came from.
That works perfectly, thanks:)

Comment: MATLAB somehow sucks at multi-page TIFF; I had very similar frustration recently.
Use this instead: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35684-multipage-tiff-stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write multiple pages to a TIFF file is to call [`Tiff.writeDirectory`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.writedirectory.html) after each page (2D image) has been written. I agree, the MATLAB documentation is not very clear there, knowing [LibTIFF](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/) helps in using the `Tiff` class. For example:

```matlab
image = zeros([140,160,16],'uint8'); % this is the image we'll write, should have some actual data in it...

t = Tiff('testing.tif','w');
tagstruct.ImageLength = size(image,1);
tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(image,2);
tagstruct.SampleFormat = 1; % uint
tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack;
tagstruct.BitsPerSample = 8;
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 1;
tagstruct.Compression = Tiff.Compression.Deflate;
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;
for ii=1:size(image,3)
   setTag(t,tagstruct);
   write(t,image(:,:,ii));
   writeDirectory(t);
end
close(t)
```